# C# if-statements inside a if-statement with a random value as modifier

Tags: c#, if-statement

The code outputs all of the writelines instead of just a single one. I know there are some kind of array that could make this more simple but i dont know it at its fullest yet.
Note that some code is deleted because i didn't want to fill the page.

```
            //Förberedelser
            Random numberGenerator = new Random();
            int num01 = numberGenerator.Next(2, 10);
            int num02 = numberGenerator.Next(2, 10);
            int svarSvar = numberGenerator.Next(1, 6);

            int numKey = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("");
            if (numKey == num01 * num02)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                if (svarSvar == 1);
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("GoGött du du vann! :D");
                }
                if (svarSvar == 2);
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Kanoners du klarade den fint du!");
                }
                if (svarSvar == 3);
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Tror inte ens att tomten skulle ta den så bra som du gjorde.");
                }
                if (svarSvar == 4);
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("placeholder");
                }
                if (svarSvar == 5);
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("placeholder");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.Write("\n Du svarade tyvärr fel. \n Svaret är: ");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                Console.WriteLine(num01 * num02);
            }

            //Avslut och loop
            Console.ReadKey();
            Console.Clear();
```

Comment: `if` statements don't have a `;` after them. If you put one, it is interpreted as an empty statement, which then becomes the body of the `if`. Your `{}` block then is no longer inside the body of the if. Pay attention to compiler warnings. It almost certainly would have told you this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the semi-colon at the end of the `if()` lines:

```
 if (svarSvar == 1);
```

Technically, the `if()` and the code that is done when true, is *one* statement.  It is clearer if we get rid of the braces:

```
 if (svarSvar == 1)  Console.WriteLine("GoGött du du vann! :D");
```

That's all one statement, with a semi-colon only at the ever end.
When you write it like you have it, it's effectively the same as:

```
 if (svarSvar == 1)
     /* empty statement here */     ;
 {
      Console.WriteLine("GoGött du du vann! :D"); // not attached to if(), always done.
 }
```

Comment: okay thank you very much sir. I will flag you as right answer in some minutes. :D

Answer (score 1):

Remove the semicolon after a if statement. And you should look into switch statements instead :)

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is a switch statement:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

```
switch (svarSvar)
    case 1:
        Console.WriteLine("GoGött du vann! :D");
        break;
    case 2:
        Console.WriteLine("Kanoners du klarade den fint du!");
        break;
```

etc.

Comment: I have a C# sharp book right beside me, i will look up switch statements and have a good read. :D thank you.

Comment: Okay, think about up-voting every answer you like.